# How to call my Web API controller when using dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2

I want to route all of my calls to the database through my web api controller. The problem is I am using ninject to dependency inject services into my web api controller. So when My MVC controller needs to call to the web api controller I cannot just instantiate a new instance of it or I have to pass all of the injected services I use into the MVC controller and then reInject them as parameters to the api controller:

```
 UserController : Controller
 {
   {
    private readonly IGroupService _groupService;

    public UserController(IGroupService groupService)
    {
        _groupService = groupService;
    }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         var model = new UserModel();
         model.Group = _groupService.get();
         //I don't want to do this
     }
  }

   public class UserApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly IStatusConverter _statusConverter;

    public UserApiController(IUserService userService, IStatusConverter statusConverter)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _statusConverter = statusConverter;
    }

    public IEnumerable<WebUser> Get()
    {
        return _userService.Get();
    }
```

I cannot instantiate a new ApiController in my MVC controller without adding unused injection to the mvc controller. Any suggestions?

Comment: "I want to route all of my calls to the database through my web api controller." Why in gods name do you want to do that? Seems to me you're missing an abstraction. Both your Web API and MVC controller should depend on some abstraction from the business layer that communicates with the database.

Comment: I have a service layer that directly contacts the database(Thats what I am injecting above.) I am trying to only use MVC to route and use WebApi to retrieve the data to build objects